# Upadate text in text box using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net

i want to set text as default on text box and it will be update for each starting after that using vb.net 2010. as example, i need to process out progress for a stock.the default value of stock is 30, so at the first log in, value text box will show 30 as the number, user will run out process (default number - out number = result), result will be show. then if user login for next time, it will update the number as result number at the first process.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `(ApplicationSettings)` node in the Properties window to create a setting and bind it to the `Text` property of the `TextBox`.  That way, value in the control will be saved to the user config file at shutdown and loaded at startup automatically.

Comment: how to create the setting?